# AngularJS How to skip element submission when element is hidden

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown list with enum values. When the dropdownlist is hidden by ng-show, the value is still be submitted as ''. So i getting

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of MyEnum from String value '': value not one of declared Enum instance names
 at [Source: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.http.HttpInputStream@1024cb7e; line: 1, column: 349]

How do I skip the validation/submission?

`<select ng-show="itIsHideNow()" ng-model="value.myEnum"
                        ng-options="option for option in myEnumOptions">
    </select>`

Comment: Please post your submission code in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Check if element is visible before submit:

```
$("#dropdown").is(":visible")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-if instead of ng-show.
How do you send your form?

Comment: $http.post(model).success(function (data) {

            })